# Avoiding execution of some PL/PGSQL functions by query rewriting

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, plpgsql

I would like to allow the execution of a PL/PGSQL function (`my_function`) only if its argument (`my_table.x`) belongs to a predefined interval (e.g. [100,1000]).

Let's take the following query example :

(q)  `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_function(mytable.x);`

I would like this query automatically rewrites itself to check whether `mytable.x` belongs to the interval [100,1000] :

(q')  `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (my_table.x BETWEEN 100 AND 1000) AND my_function(my_table.x);`

The command `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` shows that the second query is really faster than the first one.

How can I change the query execution plan in order to automate the process of query rewriting (q into q') ?
Where can I store suitably the metadata about the interval [100,1000] associated to `my_function` ?

Thanks by advance,

Thomas Girault

The help I need will help a project about the integration of fuzzy logics into PostgreSQL : [https://github.com/postgresqlf/PostgreSQL_f/][PostgreSQLf]

Comment: The function `my_function` calls the following function CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION low(val double precision)
  RETURNS double precision AS
$BODY$
   SELECT trapezoidal_fuzzy_predicate($1, 0,0,1000,100000);$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to catch it is something like this *at the top of the function body*:

```
IF $1 BETWEEN 100 AND 1000 THEN
   -- proceed
ELSE
   RETURN NULL; -- Or what ever you want to return in this case
END IF;
```

This should be *very* fast.

---

Actual *query rewriting* is done with the [**`RULE` system**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rules.html) in PostgreSQL. But rules apply to tables and views, not to functions. You could wrap your query in a view - but then you can add the additional condition explicitly, which is cheaper.

```
CREATE VIEW v_tbl_only_valid_x AS 
    SELECT *
    FROM   tbl
    WHERE  x BETWEEN 100 AND 1000;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM v_tbl_only_valid_x WHERE my_function(x);
```

This way the query planner gets the information about the selectivity of the query on the column `x` explicitly, which may result in a different query plan.

But wouldn't it be simpler to just add the second `WHERE` condition in your query like you have it in `q'`?

Comment: `my_function` calls a trapezoidal membership function [link](http://www.dma.fi.upm.es/java/fuzzy/fuzzyinf/funpert_en.htm) which tests first if its argument belongs to the interval [100, 1000]. Unfortunately, it is not optimized to test the membership to the interval inside `my_function`. However, with the `BETWEEN` optimisation, the membership test is done outside `my_function`.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I have already tried to integrate the membership test at the top of the function body. Unfortunately, it is not optimised.

Comment: @ThomasGirault - What do you mean on 'optimised' then?  This way your function will do close to nothing if x falls outside your interval.

Comment: According to `EXPLAIN ANALYSE`, the function call has a cost :

EXPLAIN ANALYSE VERBOSE SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE my_function(mytable.x);

"HashAggregate  (cost=107.84..108.68 **rows=67** width=43) ..."Total runtime: 12.540 ms"

We can compare the previous query by and optimised one : 

EXPLAIN ANALYSE VERBOSE SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (my_table.x between 0 AND 100000) AND my_function(mytable.x);

"HashAggregate  (cost=108.40..108.96 **rows=45** width=43) ... "Total runtime: 9.245 ms"

Comment: @ThomasGirault - and the row counts differing with the modification Erwin suggested?

Comment: Yes, the row counts differs even with the membership test at the top of the function body. The runtime difference becomes worst when the table size grows.

Comment: @ThomasGirault: I added a bit about RULES.